# Can you always add $(n-k)$ column(s) to an $n\times k$ matrix to make its determinant the specific constant?

Tags: matrices, determinant

If I have an $n\times k$ matrix with real entries and the columns are fixed, can I say, that I will always be able to add additional $(n-k)$ columns to make its determinant the constant I need? It seems to me that the answer should be yes but I am not sure and would appreciate any explanation supporting or denying this statement.

Comment: You can't if the original matrix has a column of $0$s. You probably can if they are independent - I haven't thought through a proof.

Comment: I thought you can only calculate determinants of square matrices?

Comment: Thank you, that's a good point. Does it work if there is no such column though?

Comment: I would add n-k columns which would make my new matrix a square one.

Comment: If the original columns are linearly independent then you can add $n-k$ columns which complete them to a basis of $\mathbb{R^n}$. After that, you can multiple one of the columns by a scalar, this will multiple the determinant by the same scalar and give you the value that you want.

Comment: What does $n - k $ columns mean?

Comment: I have a matrix with k columns of 'height' n. I add n-k columns to the right side to make a square nxn matrix.

Comment: Thank you for the answers!

Comment: Oh I see. $n$ take away $k$...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it if and only if the original columns are linearly independent. If they are dependent then no matter what columns you add, they will be dependent and so the determinant will always be $0$.

On the other hand, if the columns are independent then you can add $n-k$ columns which complete them to a basis of $\mathbb{R^n}$. This matrix will have a nonzero determinant, let's call it $c$. Then to get a matrix with determinant $d$, you can simply multiply the last column by the scalar $c^{-1}d$. So indeed you can complete the original matrix to a matrix in $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ with any determinant.